# Different costs for underestimation and overestimation

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, random-forest

I have a regression problem, but the cost function is different: The cost for an underestimate is higher than an overestimate. For example, if predicted value < true value, the cost will be 3*(true-predicted)^2; if predicted value > true value, the cost will be 1*(true-predicted)^2.

I'm thinking of using classical regression models such as linear regression, random forest etc. What modifications should I make to adjust for this cost function?

As I know, the ML API such as scikit-learn does not provide the functionality to directly modify the cost function. If I have to use these APIs, what can I do?

Any recommended reading?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Tensorflow (or theano) for custom cost functions. The common linear regression implementation is [here](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/linear_regression.py).

To find out how you can implement your custom cost function looking at a huber loss function implemented in tensorflow might help you. Here comes your custom cost function which you should replace in the linked code so instead of

```
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
```

in the linked code you'll have:

```
error = y_known - y_pred
condition = tf.less(error, 0)
overestimation_loss = 1 * tf.square(error)
underestimation_loss = 3 * tf.square(error)    
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.where(condition, overestimation_loss, underestimation_loss))
```

Here when condition is true, error is lower than zero which means you y_known is smaller than y_pred so you'll have overestimation and so the tf.where statement will choose overestimation_loss otherwise underestimation loss.

The secret is that you'll compute both losses and choose where to use them using tf.where and condition.

**Update:**

If you want to use other libraries, if [huber loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss) is implemented you can take a look to get ideas because huber loss is a conditional loss function similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asymmetric cost function to make your model overestimate or underestimate. You can replace cost function in this [implementation](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/linear_regression.py) with:

```
def acost(a): return tf.pow(pred-Y, 2) * tf.pow(tf.sign(pred-Y) + a, 2)
```

for more detail see this [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10471/linear-regression-with-non-symmetric-cost-function)